# lowest and highest salaries display

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

i try to get top 5 salary and second highest from employees table but it shows me also lowest salaries

check this picture salary column

[image]

and this is the output

[image]

this is the queries which i try

```
SELECT MAX(Salary) FROM Employees
WHERE Salary NOT IN (SELECT MAX(Salary) FROM Employees )

select top 5 salary from Employees;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are doing this for learning SQL purpose. So, if you can convert the salary column to integer ([Alter table, Alter column](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alter.asp)), that will really help you and your queries will become as simple as below:

For 2nd highest:

```
SELECT max(salary)
FROM employees
WHERE salary < (SELECT max(salary) 
                FROM employees);
```

'<' or '<>' are more efficient here, as 'NOT IN' is a costly operation.

and for Top 5:

```
SELECT TOP 5 salary 
FROM   employees 
ORDER  BY salary DESC;
```

Else as told above, you will have to convert it on the fly or give ranks to the rows.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are not getting correct result is because you are saving `salary` as `string`. So `200` in `string` will be more than `1000` in `string`.
To compare 2 string, their characters are converted to `ascii` characters and then compared based on `ascii` characters. So `ascii` value of `2` in `200` is more than `1` in `1000`. Hence incorrect result.

To give your answer, this will give you rank in descending order.

<kbd>**[`SQLFiddle Demo for Top 5`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8b9bd6/4)**</kbd>

```
select salary,
rank() over(order by cast(salary as float) desc) 
as rnk from employee
```

You can use this to get anything. Like top 5

```
select * from 
(select salary,rank() over(order by cast(salary as float) desc) 
  as rnk from  employee)
where rnk <=5
```

Only second highest

```
select * from 
(select salary,rank() over(order by cast(salary as float) desc) 
  as rnk from  employee)
where rnk =2
```

Comment: Or row_number syntax

Answer (score 0):

Top function should not given top five salary but it is return top 5 record. 
If you want top 5 salary to using "order by"
like this..

```
select top 5 salary from Employees order by Convert(numeric(18,2),salary) desc;
```

Comment: i also do this but this show me same result lowest salaries displayed also in output..

Comment: any solutions please?

Comment: @scorpio it need to convert. now check it

Comment: @scorpio May I know the reason, why did you use *nvarchar* datatype for the salary?

Comment: whatever you need of requirement to convert. it may integer convert